# Any threat from typing password into user name field?

Tags: security, passwords

I have always been curious - keylogger aside, is there any risk after typing a password into the user name field at Windows logon?

Comment: It carries the same threat, as typing in your password, in the password field.  *The password field just masks your password.*

Comment: @Ramhoud not really there is slightly more. On a failed login attempt the event viewer logs the user name that tried to log in so if someone is able to see the log they will see the password as a username. A failed login attempt does not log the password field. Also if someone is glancing over your shoulder they can read the username field.

Comment: The question did not indicate an actual attempt to log into the account was made with the password int the username field.

Answer (score 4):

Besides someone looking over your shoulder and seeing it, not really. If just type it and never hit enter then there is no risk at all (baring key loggers and the like). If you hit enter then there is a slightly more risk. The Windows Event logger will log failed logins which will have the username there so if someone viewed the log they would see it.

Comment: That is kind of what I was worried about.  Are there any commonly known exploits to access Event Viewer logs without having normal access?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Keep your system fully patched and run a good anti-virus/malware. You can also lock down the event log, this link is a bit old but might help you out on that. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323076

Answer (score 1):

For your personal Windows, there's a slim chance.  For networks and applications, yes.

For applications it depends on what the application tracks in its logs.  I had an application that tracked login attempts.  It stored username, timestamp, IP Address and status among other info.  I was able to determine several passwords by seeing an unsuccessful login attempt immediately followed by a successful login attempt from the same address.  Being familiar with the userids, I could tell which ones were a result from mis-typing the ID and which ones were the passwords.

Though, since windows keeps the Event Logs, scanning the event logs for a similar situation may reveal the password.